# masonry (macy.js) doesnt work with ie 11. It works after triggering "inspect mode"

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-11, masonry

I'm using macy.js. When I'm trying to run my site on IE11 element with masonry doesn't work, but when I turn on and off "inspect element" magic becomes and suddenly it does work. Any idea how to trigger it right after website loads?

html:

```
  <div class="col-10">
    <div class="portfolio-component__images js-portfolio-component__images w-100 text-right">
      <a href="/"><img class="portfolio-component__images--image" src="images/portfolio_1.png" alt="altTex"/></a>
      <a href="/"><img class="portfolio-component__images--image" src="images/portfolio_2.png" alt="altTex"/></a>
      <a href="/"><img class="portfolio-component__images--image" src="images/portfolio_4.png" alt="altTex"/></a>
      <a href="/"><img class="portfolio-component__images--image" src="images/portfolio_3.png" alt="altTex"/></a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

js:

```
const Masonry = new Macy({
  container: '.js-portfolio-component__images',
  columns: 2,
  margin: {
    x: 24,
    y: 24
  }
})
```

Comment: How do you include Macy.js? I include it via CDN and use the code you provide, it works well in IE and Chrome. It might be the issue is in other places of your code as I can't reproduce the issue with the above codes. Could you please provide a minimal code snippet which can **reproduce the issue**? Besides, is there any error in console in IE 11? Have you tried on other machines to see if the issue still exists?

Comment: @YuZhou thanks for response! I've installed macy with npm and I'm importing it from node_modules (tried CDN aswell, still not working). IE console is clear from errors. I've just tried it on my laptop, same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have just figured this out - maybe this would be helpfull for others. All I needed to do was adding a line of code which is recalculating method when images are loaded, method from documentation:

```
macyInstance.runOnImageLoad(function () {
  console.log('I only get called when all images are loaded');
  macyInstance.recalculate(true, true);
});
```